# Harmonic dependence of magnetic field and scalar potential

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I was reading a book about electrodynamics.

the book said

> we shall now consider the special case when 'the scalar potential' and the field component depend harmonically on the $z$ coordinate (along a steady magnetic field), i.e., when 'scalar potential' and the fields contain one of the following functions (or a linear combination of them)
>   $\exp(i\beta z)$, $\exp(-i\beta z)$, $\sin(\beta z)$, $\cos(\beta z)$.

I don't understand what 'harmonic dependence' means. Does it mean kind of 'periodic'? or 'harmonic function' that satisfies Laplace's equation?

Comment: Given that the author lists only periodic functions,
it seems he uses 'harmonic' in the meaning of 'periodic'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your citation from the book, I think the definition is given:the fields contain one of the following functions (or a linear combination of them)
exp(iβz), exp(−iβz), sin(βz), cos(βz).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that the scalar magnetic potential is a harmonic function i.e the laplacian is = 0 i.e the divergence of the magnetic field is 0 (from maxwell's equations)